# How can I merge this two bits of code

Tags: c#, linq

How can I turn these two bits of code into one?

```
comCtrList = (from i in genOutList
                                  join f in genAccList
                                          on i.Contract equals f.Contract
                                  select i.Contract).ToList();

genOutList.RemoveAll(acc => comCtrList.Contains(acc.Contract));
```

Comment: What is your wanted behavior, these seem to be doing two very different things.

Comment: You could of course just inline the query `comCtrList`, I would suggest not to do so, since then the query would be executed multiple times.

Comment: Why are people having some much trouble with this code?  in short, remove all items from `genOutList` where there is an item in `genAccList` that has a matching `Contract` property

Comment: Actually, it's very simple simple. I want to join two lists on contract and I want to remove the contracts from another list. I want the joining and removing in one statement. Crystal clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
genOutList= (
                  from i in genOutList
                  where !genAccList.Any(x=>x.Contract==i.Contract)
                  select i
             ).ToList();
```

Or

```
genOutList.RemoveAll(x=>genAccList.Any(i=>i.Contract==x.Contract));
```